# Lifting a principal G-bundle to a principal bundle with structure group a covering of G

Tags: definition, lie-groups, covering-spaces, principal-bundles

Let $P\to $ be a principal $G$-bundle. Suppose $U$ covers $G$. What do we mean by a lift of $P$ with respect to $U$? Can we take $P,M,G,U$ such that no lift exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f : G \to H$ is a morphism of topological groups, there's a functor from principal $G$-bundles over $X$ to principal $H$-bundles over $X$ given explicitly by applying $f$ to Cech cocycles, and abstractly by composing the classifying map $X \to BG$ of a principal $G$-bundle (where $BG$ is the [classifying space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifying_space)) of $G$) with the induced map $Bf : BG \to BH$.

If $X \to BH$ is a principal $H$-bundle, a lift of it to a principal $G$-bundle is a bundle $X \to BG$ which, after applying the above functor $Bf$, reproduces the original bundle $X \to BH$. There are cohomological obstructions to such lifts existing; for example, if $H = SO(n), G = Spin(n)$, the question is when an oriented $n$-dimensional real vector bundle admits a [spin structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_structure), and this occurs if and only if the second [Stiefel-Whitney class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel%E2%80%93Whitney_class) $w_2 \in H^2(X, \mathbb{F}_2)$ of the bundle vanishes. You can calculate, for example, that $w_2$ of the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{CP}^2$ doesn't vanish, so $\mathbb{CP}^2$ doesn't admit a spin structure.

Comment: I read that both Stiefel-Whitney classes $w_1$ and $w_2$ need to vanish for a spin structure to exist. Where may I read a proof of this?

Comment: @Student: yes, that's starting all the way from $H = O(n)$. I started from $H = SO(n)$, which corresponds to picking an orientation, so $w_1$ already needs to vanish. I'd guess that there's a proof in Milnor-Stasheff, but not sure.

Comment: I don't think Milnor-Stasheff say anything about spin structures. You can find a proof of this basically anywhere that does (in particular Lawson-Michelsohn, Spin Geometry).